# IIS 7.5 Can't load custom HTTP Handler with codebehind file

Tags: c#, asp-classic, iis-7.5

For the past 2 days I'm trying to get my custom HTTP handler to work,
but no result. I get the following error:

> Could not load type 'AlarmHandler'. 
>   Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Could not load type
>   'AlarmHandler'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

I followed several tutorials, but i guess I'm missing something small.
I'm using the following configuration:

- IIS 7.5
- DefaultPool is set to Integrated mode
- All files are in the root directory (C:\inetpub\wwwroot)
- *NO Handler mapping defined in IIS7.5*
- Web Project

**AlarmHandler.ashx.cs**:

```
using System.Web;
public class AlarmHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    // Constructor.
    public AlarmHandler() { }


    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpRequest Request = context.Request;
        HttpResponse Response = context.Response;

        // Test code.
        Response.Write("<html>");
        Response.Write("<body>");
        Response.Write("<h1>Hello from a synchronous custom HTTP handler.</h1>");
        Response.Write("</body>");
        Response.Write("</html>");
    }


    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

**alarms.ashx**:

```
<% @ WebHandler language="C#" class="AlarmHandler" codebehind="AlarmHandler.ashx.cs" %>
```

**web.config**:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="AlarmHandler" path="*.ashx" verb="*" type="IHttpHandler" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What worked for me was changing:

```
<% @ WebHandler language="C#" class="AlarmHandler" codebehind="AlarmHandler.ashx.cs" %>
```

To:

```
<% @ WebHandler language="C#" class="Namespace.AlarmHandler" codebehind="AlarmHandler.ashx.cs" %>
```

Where `Namespace` is the namespace in which `AlarmHandler` is declared.

With this in mind, I would think that changing the handler registration to this might be a good idea:

```
<add name="AlarmHandler" path="*.ashx" verb="*" type="Namespace.AlarmHandler" />
```

As an aside, I have used HTTP handlers on many occasions and have never bothered to register them (in my case I tend to explicitly invoke them via Ajax), so this line may not even be neccessary.

**Edit:**

In this case you are not using Visual Studio, which makes things a little different in that you won't have a bin directory, so we will have to do things a bit differently with the handler.

At the moment your handler is split across an ASHX and a CS file. This would normally be fine, but in your case we will need to combine them.

This should be the contents of your `Alarms.ashx` file (you won't need the `AlarmHandler.ashx.cs` file anymore):

```
<% @ WebHandler language="C#" class="AlarmHandler" %>

using System.Web;

public class AlarmHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    // Constructor.
    public AlarmHandler() { }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpRequest Request = context.Request;
        HttpResponse Response = context.Response;

        // Test code.
        Response.Write("<html>");
        Response.Write("<body>");
        Response.Write("<h1>Hello from a synchronous custom HTTP handler.</h1>");
        Response.Write("</body>");
        Response.Write("</html>");
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

As an aside, the tutorials you have been following would almost certainly have assumed that you were using Visual Studio, which might explain some of the difficulty you encountered.

Comment: I've modified my code, but it still doesn't work. I also removed the handler registration in web.config, and then I got the following error:

 Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'Alarms.AlarmHandler'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <% @ WebHandler language="C#" class="Alarms.AlarmHandler" codebehind="AlarmHandler.ashx.cs" %>

Comment: How are you invoking the handler? Does your code work when you run it on your dev machine? Also, what was the error message you got after you changed your code but before you removed the handler registration?

Comment: In my browser I browse to http://localhost/alarms.ashx
I'm currently on my dev-machine.
Before I removed the Handler registration (after modifying the rest of my code with the ones you supplied), I just got the "Could not load type 'Alarms.AlarmHandler'." error.

Comment: Shouldn't you be browsing to localhost/alarmhandler.ashx? If you already are, be sure that `Alarms.AlarmHandler` is the fully qualified class name.

Comment: I saw in my first post, i switched the filenames, above the code examples.

My handler code is named: AlarmHandler.ashx.cs
And my ASHX file (where the codebehind line is stated) is named: alarms.ashx . So I should browse to http://localhost/alarms.ashx

Comment: Wouldn't that mean your code behind file should be called `alarms.ashx.cs`?

Comment: Did you change the `codebehind` directive in `alarms.ashx` as well?

Comment: Yes, now it says
    <% @ WebHandler language="C#" codebehind="alarms.ashx.cs" class="Alarms.AlarmHandler"  %>

Comment: You say you are using a Web Project. Do you mean an ASP.NET Web Application or an ASP.NET Web Site?

Comment: In IIS i just used the default application: Default Web Site.

Comment: Yes, but in Visual Studio is it a web site or a web application?

Comment: Oh, I'm not using visual studio. Just Notepad++ .. There's no VS installed on this machine, and the only thing i've got are files in the root of the webserver and IIS for managing stuff.

Comment: Work like charm, just add Namespace for *.ashx class!

Answer (score 2):

Just because this comes up in a Google search about httphandlers and codebehind files: all you need to do is drop the .cs file in an App_Code folder and then reference the class from the .ashx file.